# In ReactJS, how to do a blocking initialization of application?

Tags: reactjs

When my application starts I need to set up some connections and log in the user and do a few other bits and pieces. I want to block until this is all set up, and want my application code to run safe in the knowledge that certain variables exist and have been initialized etc.

Right now I do this in index.js using async and await.  Seems to work well enough.

I tried to move this logic down into a ReactJS component but couldn't find a good way to implement blocking behaviour.

I'm reluctant to declare componentDidMount as an async function because I seem to recall reading that ReactJS doesn't like that.

Can anyone suggest an effective way to do blocking initialization within ReactJS components?

Comment: Why not simply have a loading screen displayed ? Or if you really want to block React, you could call `ReactDOM.render` only after your code has run ?

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, I would say: Don't.

Instead, do this:

1. In your constructor initialize your state as much as possible with the data you're able to pass in via props.
2. In your renderer, check how much state you have, and render appropriately - this may mean rendering nothing but a 'Loading' indicator initially, or perhaps you have enough initial data to do something a little more useful than that.
3. Don't declare `componentDidMount` as an `async` function. Blocking is not the way the React object model wants to work. Instead, from inside of `componentDidMount` call a separate Promise-returning function (an `async` function will work here). In a `.then()` off of that, use the returned values to update component state via `setState()` (remember to check your binding so that'll work). That'll in turn cause `render()` to be executed again, now with the necessary state to render more fully. You can even do this as several separate promises (if the async calls aren't dependent on each other), progressively updating until you have everything.

This is how React 'wants' to work, at least to my best understanding of the idiom. I've chosen to shortcircuit this in various ways in my own projects in the past (for instance, running all of the async prep before even instantiating the React component, so everything can be passed in via props), and in each case I've eventually reached a point of complexity where it became clear that just accepting the designed flow of React and working within it rather than fighting it was going to make the result more user-responsive and less convoluted. If I were going to go back and write that code again, I'd do it as described above.

Comment: Agreed - avoid blocking render if possible. If you’re using thunks or sagas and can initialize a ‘base state’ which is unauthorized, then you can show a loading screen and dispatch or trigger an action/promise that does all that logic, mapping the state to props on your top level component so that when eg logged_in is true (as the result of a saga or thunk async call), it re-renders automatically.